# Which version of flexmojos should be used?

Tags: apache-flex, maven-2, air, flexmojos

Recently I reorganized my Adobe AIR project as a maven project so I could hook into my continuous integration server.  Most of the information I found to get it working came from various blogs, which seems to be the only way to go as far as flex stuff is concerned.

When I was deciding which super-pom to inherit from, though, I found that there are a bunch of different flexmojos super-poms that different people are using.

Here are a few that I found (with each of these in use by some examples in the wild)

- [org.sonatype.flexmojos](http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/sonatype/flexmojos/flexmojos-air-super-pom/) *(this is the one I used)*
- [info.flex-mojos](http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/info/flex-mojos/air-super-pom/)
- [info.rvin.mojo](http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/info/rvin/mojo/air-super-pom/)

**What is the difference between the various super-poms and which is the de facto standard?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Velo moved the flexmojos codebase to Sonatype, we're currently updating the site.  Until the site is ready, you can read the latest information about Flexmojos on the Sonatype Forge Wiki: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/FLEXMOJOS/Home

There is a site for flexmojos at http://flexmojos.sonatype.org

The Flexmojos chapter in Maven: The Definitive Guide is still in development, but if you read it, you'll notice that there is a big difference between the previous versions of Flexmojos and the newer 3.0 release.  Namely, you can depend upon the repository hosted at repository.sonatype.org to obtain all of the necessary Flex open source artifacts.

What is the difference between the super POMs?   Quick answer is that the upcoming 3.1 release (this week) is going to move away from using super POMs to add in all of the plugin information.  Using typed Super POMs isn't something compatible with the way that most organizations use Maven.   Usually there is a corporate POM or a top-level POM in a project.  With the 3.1 release of Flexmojos you are going to see more stand-alone POMs from the flexmojos archetypes that allow Flexmojos projects to be integrated into larger, more complex multi-module Maven projects.

Comment: Thanks!  Many of the google hits apparently point to old info.  Does this mean I'll get burned if I still point to the org.sonatype superpom?  Also, this explains why the 3.1-SNAPSHOT failed with flexunit and 3.0 worked fine: you guys haven't "released" 3.1 yet!  Thanks again!

Comment: The 3.0 release was cut about two weeks ago, and it works.   The only problem is that it the archetypes rely on references to super POMs to add in all the plugin information for a project.  3.1 should be this week - once it is cut, I'll write the doc.

Comment: 3.1.0 release was just cut, but it'll take us a few hours to get doco updated.